# What is the angle between the North Celestial Pole and the Galactic Equator?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, astrophysics, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics

I’m trying to back-calculate a value in astronomy using spherical trigonometry. Using the following formula, where $δ$ = the Declination of the Galactic North Pole in degrees (i.e., the angle between the North Celestial Pole and the Galactic Equator).

Given that

$$\arccos(\sin(δ)\cos(23.43928°)-\sin(192.8583°)\cos(δ)\sin(23.439289°)) = 60.18894°$$

where

- $23.43928° =$ obliquity of the Ecliptic (tilt of Earth's axis relative to Ecliptic North Pole)
- $192.8583° =$ right ascension of Galactic North Pole in degrees
- $60.18894° =$ angle between the Galactic and Ecliptic North Poles (or the angle between the Galactic and Ecliptic Planes)
- $δ =$ declination of Galactic North Pole using Equatorial Coordinates

Can you solve for $δ$?

I've tried doing the calculation for δ in Excel, Wolfram Alpha, and "3.2. Galactic and equatorial coordinates" at https://aas.aanda.org/articles/aas/full/1998/01/ds1449/node3.html, but $δ$ is always given as a known value, i.e., 27.41 degrees, but I've had no luck in finding out how $δ$ is calculated in the first place.

You may ask, why do I want to calculate $δ$ if I already know its value? Call it intellectual curiosity, or the satisfaction of knowing the answer to something I've been struggling with for the past 5 years.

Comment: Don't spend an excessive amount of time on a single problem, that is how you fail. If the problem is reasonably complicated, then spend no more than a week trying to figure it out, then move on to the next problem. You have to learn how to manage your time and not spend that time on problems that will bring little to no value to your learning, and in your case, intellectual curiosity.

Comment: I didn't spend an excessive amount of time on it in one go. I just kept coming back to it over time. I asked here because I thought I might get an actual answer to the question itself.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how to solve for $\delta$ the following trig expression involving $\sin \delta$ and $\cos \delta$.

$$ A \sin \delta+B \cos \delta = C \tag{1}$$

Presenting below are two different methods for the same problem. In your case, use one of the two to find $\delta$.

1. **Trig expansion**

   Consider $\delta$ having two parts $\delta= \varphi + \psi$ and expand the trig function to

   $$ \cos \psi \left( B \cos \varphi+A \sin \varphi \right) + \sin \psi \left( A \cos \varphi - B \sin \varphi \right) = C \tag{2} $$

   Now you force $A \cos\varphi - B \sin\varphi =0$ since the choice of how to split $\delta$ is  ours.

   $$ \varphi =  \mathrm{atan}\left(\frac{A}{B}\right) $$

   And the equation (2) is now

   $$ \cos\psi \left( \sqrt{A^2+B^2} \right) + \sin \psi \left( 0 \right) = C $$

   which is solved for

   $$ \psi = \pm\, \mathrm{acos}\left( \frac{C}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}} \right) $$

   Putting $\delta$ back together we have the solution

   $$ \delta = \mathrm{atan}\left(\frac{A}{B}\right) \pm\, \mathrm{acos}\left( \frac{C}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}} \right) \tag{3}$$
2. **Trig substitution**

   Consider the tan half-angle substitution, $t = \tan \left( \frac{\delta}{2} \right)$ which yields the following expressions
   $$ \cos \delta = \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2} \tag{4}$$
   $$ \sin \delta = \frac{2 t}{1+t^2} \tag{5}$$
   $$ \delta = 2 \,\mathrm{atan}(t) \tag{6}$$

   And use these in (1) to get a polynomial in terms of $t$

   $$ A \frac{2 t}{1+t^2} + B \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2} = C $$

   $$ (B+C) t^2 -2 A t + (C-B) = 0 \tag{7}$$

   Solve the quadratic for $t$ and use it in (6)

   $$\delta= 2 \mathrm{atan}\left( \frac{A \pm \sqrt{A^2 + B^2 - C^2 }}{B+C} \right) \tag{8} $$

Even though (3) and (8) are different expressions, the numeric results are the same. But note the usual quadrant restrictions that go with trig functions.

---

Consider the simple example of $2 \sin\delta+ 3 \cos \delta = 1$

If you apply any of the methods above you will find $\delta \approx -40.207818721 °$ and $\delta \approx 107.58795377 °$ as the two solutions.

---

Based on the comments by @DavidHammen there is a special case when $B+C=0$. In that case the solution to (7) is $t = \frac{C}{A}$ or

$$\delta = 2\, \mathrm{atan}\left( \frac{C}{A} \right)$$

Comment: You beat me to it. My partially written answer goes down the drain! Personally I like the tangent half angle expression (your equation 8) because that form makes the quadrant restrictions go away. The 360° (or $2\pi$) issue doesn't go away, but who cares?

Comment: @DavidHammen - You should submit your answer anyway, as there are always things to be learned from the nuances of different approaches.

Comment: My answer was your essentially equations (4) to (8). There's no need to write that up. There is one interesting case you didn't cover: What if $B+C=0$?

Comment: @DavidHammen, great suggestion. I have added this to the answer.

Comment: @user52025 in (3) $\theta = \varphi + \psi$ and $\varphi = {\rm atan}(A/B)$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and the work you put into this, but I'm wondering what happened to φ in these calculations.
I'm just a layman, with an undergrad's understanding of trig, and little to none of spherical trig.
But I think I may have found another hint in an old post from the Stack Exchange:
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/88663/converting-between-galactic-and-ecliptic-coordinates by user6972:
δ=sin−1(sin(β)∗cos(ϵ)+cos(β)∗sin(ϵ)∗sin(λ))
However, I still can't figure out what the values are for β, ϵ, and λ. If I did, I could "punch them into a spreadsheet" and find φ !

Comment: φ = cos-1(A^2 + B^2 - C^2)/( 4 A B)?

Comment: No, as I stated above $\varphi = {\rm atan}(A/B)$.

Comment: None of the above responses answer the original question, at least not in a way that I can understand.

If I ask Wolfram to solve arccos(sin(δ)cos(23.43928°)sin(192.8583°)cos(δ)sin(23.439289°))-60.18894°=0 the result is: δ = 0.473325 Radians converting Radian to Degrees, I get δ = 0.473325*(180/π) = 27.12837° Using Stellarium, I get δ = 27° 7' 41.7" = 27.12825° So δ = 27.128 is close enough for me.

In the answers given above, I don't know what A, B or C mean, so this is as close as I'll ever get to teasing δ out of arccos(sin(δ)cos(23.43928°)sin(192.8583°)cos(δ)sin(23.439289°))=60.18894°.

Comment: @Astrofan - transform the equation to $$ \sin(δ)\cos(23.43928°)-\sin(192.8583°)\cos(δ)\sin(23.439289°) =\cos( 60.18894°) $$ and get the $A$, $B$ and $C$ coefficients by matching and using $\delta = \theta$ in notation.

Comment: I edited the answer to use $\delta$ as the unknown, instead of $\theta$.

Answer (score 0):

$$ \delta = \arcsin \left( \frac{\cos \left( \theta \right)}{\sqrt{a^{2} + b^{2}}} \right) + \arctan \left( \frac{b}{a} \right) = 27.13^{o} $$

where

$23.43928^{o} =$ obliquity of the Ecliptic (tilt of Earth's axis relative to Ecliptic North Pole)

$192.8583^{o} =$ right ascension of Galactic North Pole in degrees

$60.18894^{o} =$ angle between the Galactic and Ecliptic North Poles (or the angle between the Galactic and Ecliptic Planes)

With the substitutions:

$$ a = \cos \left( 23.43928^{o} \right) \approx 0.9174821 $$
$$ b = \sin \left( 192.8583^{o} \right) \cdot \sin \left( 23.439289^{o} \right) \approx −0.0885216 $$
$$ \theta = 60.18894^{o} $$

Calculations for deriving $\delta$ are at: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/53312/calculate-declination-of-galactic-n-pole-given-obliquity-of-ecliptic-rt-ascen/53313?noredirect=1#comment119196_53313